# Insert Java Code inside MatLab

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-guide

I just want to know if to include Java code inside a MatLab application is a MatLab 'valid' feature or if it's an undocumented Feature?

For example, do something like that

```
% Creates de Frame
f = javax.swing.JFrame();
f.setSize(400,400);

topPanel = javax.swing.JPanel();
topPanel.setLayout(java.awt.BorderLayout);
f.getContentPane().add(topPanel);

% Create the panel for tab 1
panel1 = javax.swing.JPanel();
panel1.setLayout('');
label1 = javax.swing.JLabel('Username:');
label1.setBounds(10, 15, 100, 35);
panel1.add(label1);

nameField = javax.swing.JTextField();
nameField.setBounds(10, 40, 150, 20);
panel1.add(nameField);

label2 = javax.swing.JLabel('Password:');
label2.setBounds(10, 60, 150, 20);
panel1.add(label2);

fieldPass = javax.swing.JPasswordField();
fieldPass.setBounds(10, 80, 150, 20);
panel1.add(fieldPass);

btnAceptar = javax.swing.JButton('OK');
btnAceptar.setBounds(10, 180, 100, 40);
panel1.add(btnAceptar);
set(btnAceptar,'MouseReleasedCallback', @(handle,evt)...
    helpdlg([ 'The user names is: ' char(nameField.getText()) ] ));


panel2 = javax.swing.JPanel();
panel2.setLayout(java.awt.GridLayout(3, 2));

panel2.add(javax.swing.JLabel('Field 1:'));
panel2.add(javax.swing.JTextField());
panel2.add(javax.swing.JLabel('Field 2:'));
panel2.add(javax.swing.JTextField());

% Create a tabbed pane
tabbedPane = javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab('MyTab1', panel1);
tabbedPane.addTab('MyTab2', panel2);
topPanel.add(tabbedPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

f.show;
waitfor(f);
```

is a (un) documented feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is in the documentation, see `doc java`, I'd consider it documented. ;-) However, the details of the Java GUI of Matlab which you can manipulate using Matlab's Java support, as reported on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/, are, well, undocumented.